# TreeMap que acepte tres datos

Tags: java, map

Estoy utilizando un `TreeMap` para almacenar palabras de un texto y las coordenadas (renglón , columna) de cada palabra, `TreeMap` esta definido como:

```
TreeMap<String, Double> mapa= new TreeMap<String, Double>();
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: puedo agregar mas campos al parámetro `Double`? para que quedara de la siguiente forma:

```
TreeMap<String, Double, Double> mapa= new TreeMap<String, Double, Double>();
```

y así poder ingresar la <"palabra", columna, renglón >

Comment: No, Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una clase `Coordenadas` que incluya columna y reglon y usar el TreeMap así `Map<String, Coordenadas> mapa = new TreeMap<String, Coordenadas>();`

Comment: @JDev, tu comentario es una respuesta perfectamente válida, te animo a publicarlo como una :)

Comment: @OscarGarcia hecho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es incorrecto:

```
TreeMap<String, Double, Double> mapa= new TreeMap<String, Double, Double>();
```

puesto que **[TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) únicamente permite 2 argumentos**,

```
TreeMap<K,V>
```

donde:

`K`: Clave definida por este mapa

`V`: Valor, el tipo de valores asignados, valor al que se asigna la clave especificada, o nulo si este mapa no contiene ninguna asignación para la clave.

---

Puedes almacenar la información que necesitas, puesto que precisamente el **[TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)** permite almacenar datos de estructura jerárquica en pares clave/valor (estructura de árbol).

Cuando deseas agregar más de un valor, en este caso se crea un objeto en el cual puedes almacenar los valores que necesitas.

Ejemplo:

```
   public static class Coordenadas {

        private double latitud;
        private double longitud;

        public Coordenadas(double latitud, double longitud){
            this.latitud = latitud;
            this.longitud = longitud;
        }

        //Setters y getters 
        public double getLatitud() {
            return latitud;
        }

        public void setLatitud(double latitud) {
            this.latitud = latitud;
        }

        public double getLongitud() {
            return longitud;
        }

        public void setLongitud(double longitud) {
            this.longitud = longitud;
        }

    }
```

Para crear tu Map este sería un ejemplo:

```
    TreeMap<String, Coordenadas> mapa= new TreeMap<String, Coordenadas>();        

    mapa.put("México City", new Coordenadas(-99.133208, 19.432608));
    mapa.put("Bogota", new Coordenadas(-74.072092, 4.710989));
    mapa.put("Lima", new Coordenadas(-77.042793, -12.046374));
    mapa.put("Buenos Aires", new Coordenadas(-58.381593, -34.603723));
    mapa.put(" Madrid", new Coordenadas(-3.703790, 40.416775));
```

Answer (score 9):

No, lo que tienes que hacer es crear una clase `Coordenadas` que incluya columna y reglon

```
public class Coordenadas {
    private double columna;
    private double renglon;

    //Setters y getters 
}
```

Luego podras usar el TreeMap así

```
Map<String, Coordenadas> mapa = new TreeMap<String, Coordenadas>();
```